# Cannot ping from a bridged inteface

Tags: networking, ping, bridge

I  am  trying to bridge between `eth2` and `br0`  from Ubuntu 11.04 within virtual box. There is network bridging to host physical machine.

From the  guest OS  after bridging I  can ping from `br0`  but  not from `eth2`. Why?

`ping -I eth2 bbc.co.uk`:

```
PING bbc.co.uk (212.58.241.131) from 172.16.4.186 eth2: 56(84) bytes of data.
From VirtualBox.local (172.16.4.103) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From VirtualBox.local (172.16.4.103) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

`ping -I br0  bbc.co.uk`

```
PING bbc.co.uk (212.58.241.131) from 172.16.4.186 br0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from virtual-vip.thdo.bbc.co.uk (212.58.241.131): icmp_req=1 ttl=239 time=31.2 ms
```

My  */etc/network/interfaces* is  as follows

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 172.16.4.186
        network 172.16.4.255
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 172.16.4.255
        gateway 172.16.4.1
        bridge_ports eth2
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

the  gateway is

`route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.4.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 br0
172.16.4.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
172.16.4.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth3
```

`ifconfig`

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4a:08:57  
          inet addr:172.16.4.186  Bcast:172.16.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe4a:857/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2969 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:267 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:200777 (200.7 KB)  TX bytes:28141 (28.1 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:df:f5:a7  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:392 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3904 (3.9 KB)  TX bytes:55700 (55.7 KB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:4a:08:57  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19849 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1206 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1631595 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:114927 (114.9 KB)

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:50:00:2d  
          inet addr:172.16.4.103  Bcast:172.16.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe50:2d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1625905 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:17450 (17.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12544 (12.5 KB)  TX bytes:12544 (12.5 KB)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the intended behaviour. If you connect eth2 to a bridge then eth2 becomes unusable (even with an IP address). You use br0 on the software side, eth0 is used physically.

In general when talking about bridges it makes sense to give the output of `brctl show`

Answer (score 2):

There is no ipaddress on interface `eth2`.

This is also the problem.

Comment: @mdpc, how is this not an answer?  It seems pretty clear to me.  If you want to ping something you must have an IP.  NO Internet Protocol address basically means No Internet Protocol communication.

Comment: Why is that a problem? eth2 is a bridging interface and shouldn't have an IP address. br0 has an IP address.

Comment: `ping -I eth2 bbc.co.uk` he forced ping to use interface eth2 with no ip address.

Comment: Right, so the problem is that he forced ping to use interface eth2, not that eth2 has no IP address. It should have no IP address. It just shouldn't be pinged from.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You have to differentiate the best practice and how the software is behaving. I see no problem on sending a raw IP packet on an interface that has no IP address. For example you can send an UDP packet (like Wake On LAN) on the broadcast IP address with a unicast MAC address to wake up a computer, the source can be a layer 2 equipment, which does not care about the answer.

Comment: I have a problem on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538023/linux-bridge-network-influenced-by-default-route

Answer (score 2):

This is as it should be. Ping is a layer 3 thing. A bridged interface is a purely layer 2 thing. You can't ping from an Ethernet cable either for the same reason. Just like a pure switch has no idea what ping is, a pure switching interface has no idea what ping is either.